# Does log every request parameter and returns in INFO level necessary?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logback

i have a `RequestAspect`, it will intercept every request. log the joinPoint's Args and log the return object in INFO level.in the way,i can easy find the error in product environment.but i my mind,log frequently will decrease performance.how much  performance will be effected . is it a good decision to have the `RequestAspect` and what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Aspect for capturing the args, you can achieve the same by just defining a Filter. Consider using `OncePerRequestFilter` to scan each request once and only once.

- Capture the http-method, request-params, request-body from the `HttpServletRequest`.
- Log the method, parameters and the *time taken to complete the request*.

[Working Example can be found here](https://snmaddula.bitbucket.io/spring-boot-execution-time-logging/)

Comment: The key is how much performance Aspect affects, not which way

Comment: To answer `how much`, you need to time every interception, which you can add in your Aspect advice methods before / after time difference logging.